# unable to execute hive query with 'Where' clause

Tags: hiveql

I have trying to execute a hive query on hadoop cluster.
Query1 - select * from test;
Result - Success

However, When I try to execute 
Query2 - Select * from test where id = 1;
Result - Failure

```
Error message:
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1508135952891_0012_2_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1508135952891_0012_2_00_000050, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_e23_1508135952891_0012_01_000184 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=1. Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e23_1508135952891_0012_01_000184
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema of the table?

Comment: This is my external table.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
`timestamp` timestamp,  
id int,
msg_parts int,
string_id int,
host string,
IPaddress string,
Username string,
Action string,
Service string
)
partitioned by (day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' LOCATION '/loc1/loc2/test/';

Comment: With provided information, I would suggest you to check the data first. Please check if your JSON has {"id" : 1,} or {"id":"1"}. If it is as mentioned as    in second case, please update your create table statement to have ID as string.

Comment: select * from test; works but whenever I use any clause like 'where', I get the below error.
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+122,-87)/332 
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+122,-88)/332 
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+0,-91)/332 
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1508339292187_0006_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1508339292187_0